# Texture in edit and object view is a jumbled mess, in cycles render it looks correct

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, texturing, node-editor

As title states, so far cross fingers my model looks ok with texture applied in cycles render view. However it recently became a mess of texture, all mixed around, scaled wrong, parts missing in object 3d view or edit 3d view! The uv editor space, the texture and UV map are fine and unchanged. I haven't changed the UVs since working on the texture. 
I previously was working with the same image size in photoshop that I exported UVs png from Blender. I was saving back to that same png file name, until most recently I decided to work on an enlarged psd file for adding more texture detail. I than saved a flattened version of that to the same png file name as before, but went with a larger image size for that png. Then when I tried to load the image into UV editor and the node as well under image texture node, the object view became the mess I'm describing. What's worse is all the previous files have the same scrambled mess texture in object mode even though they are calling back to older png files that worked fine before! I opened them up and without making any changes, the textures also are a mess. Is this a graphics card issue or some setting in Blender I have to reset in nodes or something? I'm using cycles render and nodes.

[image]

Comment: Can post the .blend? (pack the images via the File->Export data menu) https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Also try Ctrl+A and applying any Transforms, scale, translate, rotate.

Comment: Apparently the texture looks ok now. I shut down the computer last night, restarted this morning in safe mode to try and clear out some stuff, than started up again as usual, opened the project folder and looks like object/edit views are now back to projecting texture correctly.

Comment: I can see about posting it if I get more bugs occurring, and I may need to try to get the latest version downloaded in a bit to make sure I avoid certain issues. Thanks!